A high-school physics question on waves
I got a question asking about waves that may have the wrong answer, of which I'm not quite certain. Please help me. Thank you.

The figure below depicts a transverse wave that travels to the right. The dotted line is the waveform at $t=0$, and the solid line is the waveform at $t=0.5$ with $t$ measured in seconds. If the period of this wave is $T$ seconds, and $0.2<T<0.3$, then:

Q: What is the speed $v$ of this wave?
A: $v=14$ m/s

My idea: Based on the description, we can only infer that $0.5=\frac{7}{4}T$ or $0.5=\frac{11}{4}T$. The wavelength of this wave is $4$ m, so the answer should be two-fold: either $v=14$ or $v=22$. There is no point in saying that $v$ can only be of the value $14$. Does anyone have an idea? Thank you.

$0.5=\frac{11}{4}T \Rightarrow T= \frac {2}{11}$ which falls out of the permitted range for the period, $0.2<T<0.3$.

Why not $0.5={15\over 4}T$ ?

@WillO Please see Farcher's comment. This commenter made a very good point, which should clear your confusion.

@Boar:  My comment was intended to make exactly the same point that Farcher was making.

@WillO Sorry, I was too stupid to be aware that you were trying to direct me to the right track.

@Boar:  I'm glad  you have your answer :)
